# Proxy static content only for proxyed requests

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, static-content

I have an apache serving one local app on "`/`" with its static files on "`/static`"

And another app with **`mod_proxy`**:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/example" "http://127.0.0.1:9090/"
ProxyPassReverse "/example" "http://127.0.0.1:9090/"
```

And this app does have static content on its own "`/static`" but when it comes through the proxy taques te files from the first one.

¿Is there any way to serve "`/static`" to eachone depending on were does the recuest comes from?

Comment: can you post the whole config, and some example URLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example, I would expect the tomcat static files located at `http://127.0.0.1:9090/static` to be accessible under `http://127.0.0.1/example/static` when using the proxy.

**Possible Solution 1**
I think the best practice solution would be to change to use relative paths in the tomcat app instead of absolute path, so the static files used the latter path;

```
<img src="static/my_image.jpg"></img>
```

or server root relative;

```
<img src="/example/static/my_image.jpg"></img>
```

and that would correctly serve the images e.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1/example/static/my_image.jpg
```

**possible solution 2**
Rename the apache static files to something else, and explicitly proxy the /static path to tomcat;

```
# move the locate apache static files to somewhere else;
# http://127.0.0.1/static_apache etc
ProxyPass /static http://127.0.0.1:9090/static
ProxyPassReverse /static http://127.0.0.1:9090/static
ProxyPass "/example" "http://127.0.0.1:9090"
ProxyPassReverse "/example" "http://127.0.0.1:9090"
```

Also note:

> **Ordering ProxyPass Directives**
>
> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the
>   order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So usually
>   you should sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the longest
>   URLs first. Otherwise, later rules for longer URLS will be hidden by
>   any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL.

**Possibly hacky solution**

Detect whether the request was initiated from the tomcat app by inspected the referer header;

```
RewriteEngine on
# match the app in the referer before processing the rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /example
# reverse-proxy the request to the back-end
RewriteRule ^/static(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:9090/static$1 [P]
```

(I didn't test that last solution, as it would seem just a novelty way of doing things...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't edit the files or paths in any of the two apps for the first 2 options,  the third option worked for the files that the main page requests, but when I go to some other location on the web, as the link referer is the new path, it doesn't work any more. And its a bit big and complex to add every path in the whole app.